# HTTP Client Hint headers are not sent from an iframe

Tags: html, iframe, client-hints

I have an html page which gets embedded in another website.. I have added meta tag in this html page which allows APIs to receive device model in API requests

```html
<meta http-equiv="delegate-ch" content="Sec-CH-UA-Mobile;Sec-CH-UA-Platform;Sec-CH-UA-Bitness;Sec-CH-UA-Model https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com;" />
```

[Sample index.html](https://github.com/digvijayu/iframe-client-hint-spike/blob/main/iframe/index.html)

When the page is accessed directly, it works as expected.. you can see the headers passed in all requests

[image: Model is present in the headers]

But when I embed the same page inside another webpage, the headers are not sent anymore.

[image: Sec-Ch-Ua-Model header is missing]

I have tried to add the same meta tag in the parent frame which has not worked. I have also tried to add *allow* tag to the iframe, which has not worked either

```html
<iframe src="./iframe/index.html" allow="ch-dpr;ch-ua-arch;"></iframe>
```

Comment: If there's a CORS or CSP or SameSite policy on that iframe then thatr's not unusual.

Comment: Please show textual data as text, not as pictures of text. See the FAQ [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) for more info.

Comment: @Dai For the case of CORS I had to specify the domain where it is allowed to sent, in my github spike both the pages are under the same domain but it still happens

Comment: Your cropped screenshots are insufficient to accurately diagnose the problem - or to even see that there is a problem, tbh.